# How to encode object in rails view?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, encoding

I have such controller:

```
def accumulators

    @pre_accums = Accumulator.all
    @accums = Kaminari.paginate_array(@pre_accums).page(params[:page]).per(20)
  end
```

and such view

```
-if @accums.present?
  -@accums.each do |a|
    = a.model
    = a.get_accum_price(a.id)
    %br
= paginate @accums
```

now it looks like this:

```
Áýðåí ïðîôè 35ç (535151) 300A 187x127x220 ðóñ.òîíê.êëåìû 47.0 
Áýðåí ïðîôè 44ç (544107) 390A 207x175x190 45.0
```

but in db i have strange data encoding) it's encoding is iso-8859-15 (to of db table) and i must convert it ti cp1251. But how to do it in view only for  `= a.model`

?

So encode like "ISO-8859-15:CP1251"

Comment: you are probably looking for `Iconv`

Comment: @mkk and how to use it on my example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The syntax and the process depends on the database you use. Here's a use case when you can just change the character set for the current database for MySQL:

```
ALTER TABLE table_name CHARACTER SET "ISO-8859-15:CP1251";
```

This use case is when you achieve the same thing but taking different steps. In postgresql (you can do the same thing in the mysql), you have to take a dump of the current database, delete it, create a new database with the desired encoding and import data from the dump:

```
pg_dump database_name > outfile
DROP DATABASE database_name
CREATE DATABASE database_name ENCODING 'LATIN1';
psql database_name < infile
```

Comment: main trouble is in that i have many coding on one column in table... some are in that.. some in that.

Comment: That's pretty much a recipe for doom, unless you can populate a column which specifies which encoding is used in that record.

Comment: @brabertaser1992 Why would you do that? What are you trying to achieve? What kind of data are you storing?

Comment: @instinctious non my data... get form another russian app

Comment: That was just an example, you cited that character set as something that you need. Find one that fits your data. I'd agree with @dpassage about changing encoding on a column basis being a bad idea.